# What do we say for consulting a doctor as a continuation to our previous diagnosis

Tags: phrase-requests

What term do we use for consulting a doctor as a continuation to our previous diagnosis, is it a review-consultation or a follow-up consultation?

Answer (score 1):

***[Follow-up visit](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/follow-up-visit)***

(British English- medicine, social welfare)

> a visit made as a follow-up to an initial visit
>
> - Patients still typically wait 20 days for a routine follow-up visit.

(Collins)